# MONGODB ERROR 14

Tags: command-line, server, package-management, mongodb

```
Mar 27 16:13:41 localhost systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Mar 27 16:13:42 localhost systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Mar 27 16:13:42 localhost systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@localhost:~# systemctl restart mongod
root@localhost:~# systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-03-27 16:13:55 UTC; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 8778 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 8778 (code=exited, status=14)

Mar 27 16:13:54 localhost systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Mar 27 16:13:55 localhost systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Mar 27 16:13:55 localhost systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Attempted solution: Switching owners

```
Commands Run
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod restart
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Still failed regardless of restarts and switching owners

Comment: What is the output of `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jq7d7WFe

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in log file /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I created a data/db folder and this fixed the issue immediately

Comment: Where did you create it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, therefor I install mongodb 4.0 so when I remove it but not data then mongodb 5 can not use this. These is my steps:

1. sudo tail -40 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log and read somes log relative to mongodb "This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."

2. cd /var/lib/mongodb and remove all items

3. Run **sudo mongod --repair --config /etc/mongod.conf**

4. Run **sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb**

5. Run **sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**

6. Run **sudo systemctl start mongod**

7. Run **sudo systemctl status mongod**

 If above dont work, try this: **sudo mongod**

And everything work.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem. I installed MongoDB-org a couple of times and every time my system reboots it failed to restart the MongoDB server.

What I found that the problem was something with the startup. So I reinstalled the MongoDB-org following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)  documentation and didn't run `sudo systemctl enable mongod` which is for running MongoDB automatically on startup.
And everything work fine.

Although the downside is that you have to start the MongoDB server every time you do logout or reboot the system by `sudo systemctl start mongod`.